# How to cross-validate contact form 7 form fields?

Tags: contact-form-7

I want to make two sperate check box groupe. Lets say

```
Front end courses
-Bootstrap
-React Js
-Angular js

Back end courses
-C#
-Node
-PHP
```

on submitting form I want to make sure at least one course is selected by the user. Lets say a student selects ReactJs.

I have tried below code but it makes one option mandatory for all checkbox groups

```
[Checkbox* checkbox-11 ",Bootstrap" "React Js" "Angular JS"]

[Checkbox* checkbox-12 ",C#" "Node" "PHP"]
```

How can I make at least one option selected mandatory from any of the checkbox groups

Answer (score 0):

field validation takes place post form submission.  To solve this problem you need to make neither field mandatory, and then do a custom validation on the server side.  CF7 plugin allows you to add custom validation to individual field but does not allow you to validate a field wrt to the value of other fields in the form.

To do this you need an extension such as the [Smart Grid-layout plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which has a validation hook that gives you access to the entire form's submitted data and therefore cross-validate your fields,

```
add_filter('cf7sg_validate_submission', 'cross_validate_submission',10,3);
function cross_validate_submission($validation, $submission, $form_key){
  if(empty($submission['fe-courses']) && empty($submission['be-courses'])){
    $validation['fe-courses']='You need to select at least 1 course!';
  }
  return $validation;
}
```